# Simpson's Rule? Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

[image: Image of question]
Can somebody please show how to get the answer for this question. Very confusing, I find hints online hard to understand so full explanation would be best.

Thanks to whoever helps me out!

P.S: somehow "1,4,2,4,2,4,1." is useful but I do not know what it means.

Answer (score 1):

Simpsons rule is as follows:
Given an two intervals $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ and $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$, it can be shown that the area under a function on this interval is approximately $$A_i \approx \frac{\Delta x}{3}(f(x_{i-1}) + 4f(x_i) + f(x_{i+1})$$
if we use $n$ subintervals we obtain $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \approx \frac{\Delta x}{3}(f(x_0) + 4f(x_1) + 2f(x_{2}) + \cdots + 2f(x_{n-2}) + 4f(x_{n-1}) + 2f(x_n))$$
in your problem calculus $\Delta x$. The values of $f(x_0) \ldots f(x_n)$ are given in the chart.